# Filter AWS resources under Explorer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm, amazon-systems-manager

How I can filter AWS resources under AWS Explorer? e.g, list OpsData related to an ec2 instance with a specific tag, I tried "Related Resources Tag Key" with no luck, I tried to add the same keys I want to use in "Tags for reporting" with no luck as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it should be the answer, but I retired after a couple of hours and it worked fine! I think because I'm not using a business account AWS doesn't care much about syncing the tags or related info about my ec2 into Systems Manager.